# Get xterm to notify me when nothing's happening

Tags: notifications, gnu, xterm, terminal-emulator

Recently I found myself several times in situations where I need to let run some operation in some background xterm and I'd need to be notified when my input is requested.

I know how to make it so I'm notified when the command *ends*, but that doesn't help in the cases where the command is not 100% batch (it puts up a prompt every now and then; a common example would be `apt-get`) or where the command hangs (because of some network failure, for example).

So I'd like to be notified when there's been no output in the last N minutes.  Is there some way to configure `xterm` to do that for me, or maybe some other tool (`screen` maybe) that could do it?

Answer (score 0):

xterm doesn't notice if the application is actually waiting for input, or simply doing nothing.  An application (or shell) could be *modified* to do this, but that seems like a lot more work than you expected (i.e., many programs *could* be modified).

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know of a way how to do it for applications that might be waiting for input, but if you have a batch application that should always output log info within a certain time span then you could run an extra process that does the notification if it doesn't get killed within a timeout. The process gets killed whenever a new line is read. Maybe that will help you or someone else to adapt it to processes that might wait for input:

```
i=0;{ while true;do echo $i;((i++));sleep $i;done }|while read line;do if [ $pid ];then sudo kill $pid;fi;bash -c 'sleep 5;notify-send boom'& pid=$!;echo $line;done
```

The part before the pipe sign is a process that outputs slower and slower and if it becomes slower than the threshold, `notify-send` sends notifications. If you wanted output to happen within 3 minutes, use `sleep 3m`.